# Print column names which have null values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I was creating a procedure where i needed this part.
**Table**

```
col1   col2   col3
a      null     b
null    d      null
c       e      null
```

**Output**

```
col1   col2   col3     result
 a      null    b       col2
 null    d     null    col1,col3
 c       e     null     col3
```

Can we do it using case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would also use decode as follows.

```
select t.*, 
    rtrim(decode(col1,null,'col1,',null) 
    || decode(col2,null,'col2,',null)
    || decode(col3,null,'col3,',null),',')  as result 
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       substr( ( (case when col1 is null then ',col1' else '' end) ||
                 (case when col2 is null then ',col2' else '' end) ||
                 (case when col3 is null then ',col3' else '' end)
               ), 2)
from t;
```

Strictly speaking the `else ''` is redundant, because Oracle treats `''` as a `NULL` value.  However, I like to include it, because this behavior differs from most databases.

Comment: Thanks  linoff i'll give it a try!!

Comment: I assume the `substr` is to "correct" for the trailing comma - but `substr(input, 2)` will chop off the first character, not the last. Perhaps you meant `',col1'` etc. instead of `'col1,'` (with leading comma rather than trailing?)

Comment: You would remove the last comma by using RTRIM function instead of SUBSTR.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Thanks.  I had the comma in the wrong place.

Comment: @mathguy ... damith ..linoff  ... Thanks :)